# curl page title

Tags: php, html, curl

I am using the following code to get the **full html** from a specified page:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Question: how can this code be modified to **return the `<title>`** instead of the full html of the page. $result stores the result.

Comment: You will get the full HTML of the page, and probably a lot of JavaScript stuff, too, if you read the Google URL.  The regular expression from Ryan Naddy looks right to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the title using regular expression, I find this regex very helpful:

```
function get_html_title($html){
    preg_match("/\<title.*\>(.*)\<\/title\>/isU", $html, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't really just get the title, you can get the whole document and then weed out the elements you need: I like to use [Simple Html Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$title = $html->find('title');
```

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score -3):

Look at parsing the contents of the result

either using regex

or Dom Document